# calling method from another method which takes 3 parameters in the same class

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, method-call

I was writing a code for calculator by creating class name "calculator" which takes methods for add, subtract, multiply and divide. These methods takes two parameters and perform respective action.

Now, I have to create another method name "drive_command" which takes 3 parameters. First parameter takes the string that can be either 'add', 'subtract', 'multiply', 'divide' and the other two parameter take the numbers and it will call the specific method based on the string that we will pass in the drive_command method.

So how I supposed to call method from another method which takes parameter in the same class?

```
class calculator:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def add(self, num1, num2):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2
        return num1+num2
    def drive_command(command,x,y):
        if command == "add":
            self.add()
```

Comment: `self.add(x, y)`?

Comment: `num1` and `num2` should be initialised in your `__init__`.

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 9.3.5. Class and Instance Variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) and [What is the purpose of the word 'self'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-word-self)

Comment: Take note that an empty/no-op ``__init__`` is a good sign that you should not be using a class.

Comment: Do you know how to call the ``add`` method from *outside* the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add self parameter in drive_command function.And call self.add(x,y).

```
class calculator:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def add(self, num1, num2):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2
        return num1+num2
    def drive_command(self,command,x,y):
        if command == "add":
            return self.add(x,y)

c = calculator()
value = c.drive_command('add',10,10)
print(value)
```

Comment: If I want to make "drive_command" case-insensitive that is even if the user passes 'adD' as command it should perform addition on two numbers then what i have to do?

Comment: Just use command.lower()=='add' instead of command == 'add' in if statement inside drive_command function

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your `drive_command` line has incorrect syntax - you should have the arguments as this `drive_command(self, command, x, y)`, otherwise python will get confused. To call your `add` function, simply use the following:

```
self.add(x,y)
```

in place of

```
self.add()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Or, add `x` and `y` as class members in `drive_command`, then nothing has to be passed in to `add()`.

Comment: Yes, that could be a useful option.

Comment: Please don't suggest to carry around function arguments as attributes. There shouldn't be a class in the first place, but misusing it as a function container is far less of a code smell than indirectly passing parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `getattr` function:

```
class calculator:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def add(self, num1, num2):
        return num1+num2
    def drive_command(self, command,x,y):
        return getattr(self, command)(x, y)

c = calculator()
print(c.drive_command('add',10,10))
```